# How can I improve my beginner-level question about IOT?

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions

I had posted [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702489/beginner-in-iot-any-step-by-step-tutorials), but it was closed. Thinking better of it, I have since deleted it.

My original question was:

> ## Beginner in iot- any step by step tutorials
>
> I am a beginner in IOT.
>
> I have been reading up about the concepts .
>
> Is there any kind of tutorial available which starts from the hardware till the end.
>
> Any help is appreciated.

I've since learned that asking for tutorials is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), so I would remove that part of my question. But I'm still a total beginner, so I don't have any code to show. I've searched Google, but I just cannot understand where to begin.

How can I improve this question into something that could be asked for Stack Overflow? I really need some guidance.

Comment: That question can't be improved such that it would be on topic here.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery - thankyou for your answer. I am a total beginner in IOT. I need any tips on where to start on it. Just want to frame the question as such without being closed. Or if stackoverflow is not the place to ask for guidance then i am in wrong place.

Comment: @cody-gray thankyou for editing this.Now i get it. Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 5):

You can't, because questions asking for tutorials are fundamentally off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

This specific question cannot be edited in such a manner that it would be a good fit for StackOverflow, as you already mentioned before asking for tutorials or other off-site resources is always deemed off-topic.

> Or if stackoverflow is not the place to ask for guidance then i am in wrong place

This isn't entirely true either, StackOverflow *is* a place for guidance, but only to questions that have a specific problem with code you have written.

If for example you start writing your first IOT code, but run into a problem connecting your devices you could make a question about that *specific* issue. Granted it contains all necessary information and is not a duplicate of an already asked question.

A question like that would include information such as (but not limited to)

- A concise explanation of the problem
- [A Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- Specific errors you are getting
- The desired outcome
- Things you have already tried/researched yourself

More tips about asking a question that won't get closed and help you increase the likelyhood of getting an answer can be found in the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), or if things are still unclear you can turn to meta (as you did now).

Comment: It is true only for intermediate developers not a beginner. I have come to realise we cannot ask beginner level questions here unless we come up with a very specific problem at a later stage. So , found out a forum for beginners for now, using it and will come back when i have specific questions as a medium  level dev. Also, even this question was closed here with   "Needs details or clarity" , but was opened by a generous moderator as he had modified the post for me. But if even meta questions are closed, it is not worth asking until a certain point here. Thanks to those who answered.